# Mono throws Exception when trying to connect to MySQL-database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mono

I have a simple application (.NET 4.5.2) which makes usage of the MySQL-driver (v6.9.8) for .NET/Mono. It works perfectly on .NET (Windows) but throws an exception on Ubuntu (Mono v4.2.1) as soon as I invoke the Connect-method.

```
2016-06-21 16:21:19,659 [1] WARN  MySql.DatabaseDriverMySql [(null)] - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetterAdapterFrame[T,R] (System.Reflection.Getter`2 getter, System.Object obj) <0x7f65f01aece0 + 0x00039> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) <0x7f65f01aef20 + 0x000d9> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) <0x7f65f01aef20 + 0x00117> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs () <0x40e6a2f0 + 0x00138> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate (Boolean reset) <0x40e69830 + 0x0016b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate (System.String authMethod, Boolean reset) <0x40e68320 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () <0x40e5c9d0 + 0x00787> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () <0x40e5c980 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) <0x40e56be0 + 0x00173> in <filename unknown>:0
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetterAdapterFrame[T,R] (System.Reflection.Getter getter, System.Object obj) <0x7f65f01aece0 + 0x00039> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) <0x7f65f01aef20 + 0x000d9> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) <0x7f65f01aef20 + 0x00117> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs () <0x40e6a2f0 + 0x00138> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate (Boolean reset) <0x40e69830 + 0x0016b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate (System.String authMethod, Boolean reset) <0x40e68320 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () <0x40e5c9d0 + 0x00787> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () <0x40e5c980 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) <0x40e56be0 + 0x00173> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Are we talking mono-mac? or is this ios/android?

Answer (score 1):

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0

System.Management is a library that only works on Windows.
If the MySQL connector driver has suddenly started to depend on this library, this is pretty bad. IIRC the Mysql .NET connector has always worked with Mono, so we would need to report this problem as a regression.

Comment: The last working version of the MySQL .NET Driver is 6.4.6, since 6.5.7 it seems not to work with Mono anymore ... a bit strange because MySQL says these are Mono-drivers!?

Comment: please report it to Oracle/Mysql's bug tracking system

Answer (score 0):

Reported the bug to MySQL. Link: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81973